# RabbitMQ: fanout exchange with no message loss?

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

```
RabbitMQ:  version 3.11.2
```

I wish to configure a fanout exchange for which there will be two consumers and a single producer.  Each of the two consumers can go offline for several minutes at a time; in the worst case scenario, one of the consumers could go offline for hours.

QUESTION:  how should the fanout exchange and/or consumer queues be configured such that no message is ever lost, even if and when one of the consumers goes offline for several minutes or hours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is enough to bind queues to your exchange.

See here for more details https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-python.html

> result = channel.queue_declare(queue='')
> At this point result.method.queue contains a random queue name. For example it may look like amq.gen-JzTY20BRgKO-HjmUJj0wLg.

> Secondly, once the consumer connection is closed, the queue should be deleted. There's an exclusive flag for that:

> result = channel.queue_declare(queue='', exclusive=True)
> channel.queue_bind(exchange='logs',
> queue=result.method.queue)

Note:
If you need to handle the offline consumers, you need persistent queues and persistent messages instead of `exclusive` and `auto-delete` queues

Comment: I will be using the pub/sub pattern, and not worker-task queues or any kind of filtering.  That is, every subscriber _MUST SEE_ every message.  In that case, is what you are saying still true?

Comment: thx.  My queues will be both exclusive and durable, while exchange will be durable.  As well, for both queue and exchange, I've set `auto-delete=false`.  I believe this configuration will persist messages across both broker _AND_ client restarts.

Comment: Sorry, if you want to handle the offline status you need persistent queues and persistent messages. 

One queue for each single consumer and then bind the exchange fan out to the queues.